# PPPoE on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, pppoe

How do I change or at least check the username of a PPPoE account setup on Windows 8?

My PPPoE account and the network icon on Windows 8 were created by the ISP during the first time web access.  It works so far so good with the setup Notebook PC.  But now I want to create a WiFi coverage using a Wireless router and thus need to re-enter the PPPoE username and password to the router setup page.  Unfortunately it keeps on getting a "bad username and password" message from the remote server.  I quite sure the password is correct so may I know is there a way I can check the username of the PPPoE setup with the notebook PC using which the logon is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP will need to be contacted to get that information. There is no way to get that information from your laptop for obvious reasons (so that no one can steal it). Your ISP will most likely not give you the password that is setup, but they will change it for you to either what you ask them to change it to or to a random one which they will give you over the phone. Once you have that sorted out, you may make changes or leave it as you wish.

Comment: I actually connecting to BigAir Community Broadband.  I setup my own username and password over the web page the first time access to the network.  Entered the same my_username and password to the router setup page but didn't work.  Just wonder if it needs to be setup like my_username@bigair.net.au and password.  Did ask the ISP but no reply so far.  Many thanks.